# Turn on Airplane Mode Automcatically When Phone is Locked

Tags: iphone, ios, automation, airplane-mode

Is there a way to automate the switching of Airplane mode on when an iPhone is locked? And automatically switched off when the phone is unlocked?

Comment: What is the use case for this?

Comment: I need to have the cellular service disabled when I'm not using the phone. I need to manually enable and disable now. If I don't disable Airplance mode first before unlocking I have to dismiss a prompt to turn on cellular service. If I forget to enable airplane before locking the phone the battery gets drained. Can I automate Airplane mode when the phone is locked and unlocked?